# ESP8266 Thingspeak data doesn't show up

Tags: lua, iot, esp8266, nodemcu

I built this project:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Low-cost-WIFI-temperature-data-logger-based-on-ESP/?ALLSTEPS
The ESP8266 outputs something and I think it should be ok.
But there are no entries in the Thingspeak channel. I already double-checked the API-Write Key.
Here's the serial output:

```
Setting up WIFI...
> IP unavaiable, Waiting...
IP unavaiable, Waiting...
IP unavaiable, Waiting...
IP unavaiable, Waiting...
IP unavaiable, Waiting...
IP unavaiable, Waiting...
Config done, IP is 192.168.1.9
Last temp: 216875
Temp:21.6875.6875 C

Sending data to thingspeak.com
Last temp: 216875
Temp:21.6875.6875 C

Sending data to thingspeak.com
Got disconnection...
Last temp: 216875
Temp:21.6875.6875 C

Sending data to thingspeak.com
Got disconnection...
Last temp: 216875
Temp:21.6875.6875 C

Sending data to thingspeak.com
Got disconnection...
Last temp: 216875
Temp:21.6875.6875 C
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need any more feedback? If not then please consider accepting the answer so SO can mark this case as closed.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug in the SDK that the code in the project you referenced ever worked. In pre-1.0 SDKs `conn:send` was synchronous i.e. you could call it sequentially and it would block until each string was sent. Espressif later changed the underlying function to be *asynchronous*. Hence, the code at https://github.com/ok1cdj/ESP8266-LUA/blob/master/Thermometer-DS18B20-Thingspeak/ds1820.lua#L77 fails. See the the [`net.socket:send()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend) API documentation for more details.

However, since you're already on a recent firmware version (from the `dev` branch I believe) you should make full use of the new HTTP module. [`http.put()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/http/#httpput) is way more convenient than to operate on the raw socket.

See https://mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/update-a-channel.html for how to PUT data to ThingSpeak.

Side note: I suggest you also use DS18B20 sample code from https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/dev/lua_modules/ds18b20 provided by the NodeMCU team. That code is much more likely to be in sync with the firmware.